# trying to display a partial component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a products component that I want to display in my web design component but I only want to display two of the links in the component not all three. So when a user clicks on the main page it navigates to the webdesign portion of the application component and provides a different structure but with similar components in the application. I have three links and I only want to display two of them. Is there a way to provide this in react ?

this is my app component

```
<main className="container">
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Hero />}/>
        <Route path="/webdesign" element={<WebDesign />}/>
      </Routes>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Products />}/>
      </Routes>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Feature />}/>
      </Routes>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Modal />}/>
      </Routes>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Footer />}/>
      </Routes>
    </main>
```

this is  my web design component

```
<div className="webdesign-page">
            <h1 className="web-design-title">Web Design</h1>
            <p className="web-design-paragraph">
                We build websites that serve as powerful
                marketing tools and bring memorable brand experiences.
            </p>
            <div className="webpage-images">
                <div className="webdesign-site">
                    <img src="./assets/web-design/desktop/image-express.jpg" className="webdesign-image"/>
                    <p className="webdesign-content" >Express</p>
                    <p className="webdesign-description">A multi-carrier shipping website for ecommerce businesses</p>
                </div>
                <div className="webdesign-site">
                    <img src="./assets/web-design/desktop/image-transfer.jpg" className="webdesign-image"/>
                    <p className="webdesign-content"> TRANSFER</p>
                    <p className="webdesign-description">Site for low-cost money transfers and sending money within seconds</p>
                </div>
                <div className="webdesign-site">
                    <img src="./assets/web-design/desktop/image-photon.jpg" className="webdesign-image"/>
                    <p className="webdesign-content">PHOTON</p>
                    <p className="webdesign-description">A state-of-the-art music player with high-resolution audio and DSP effects</p>
                </div>
                <div className="webdesign-site">
                    <img src="./assets/web-design/desktop/image-builder.jpg" className="webdesign-image"/>
                    <p className="webdesign-content">BUILDER</p>
                    <p className="webdesign-description">Connects users with local contractors based on their location</p>
                </div>
                <div className="webdesign-site">
                    <img src="./assets/web-design/desktop/image-blogr.jpg" className="webdesign-image"/>
                    <p className="webdesign-content">BLOGR</p>
                    <p className="webdesign-description">Blogr is a platform for creating an online blog or publication</p>
                </div>
                <div className="webdesign-site">
                    <img src="./assets/web-design/desktop/image-camp.jpg" className="webdesign-image"/>
                    <p className="webdesign-content">CAMP</p>
                    <p className="webdesign-description">Get expert training in coding, data, design, and digital marketing</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <Products />
            <Modal />
            <Footer />
        </div>
```

this is my products component

```
<div className="products">
      <Link to="/webdesign" className="web-design">
        <h2>WEB DESIGN</h2>
        <p>VIEW PROJECTS</p>
      </Link>
      <Link to="/appdesign" className="app-design">
        <h2>APP DESIGN</h2>
        <p>VIEW Projects</p>
      </Link>
      <Link className="graphic-design">
        <h2>GRAPHIC DESIGN</h2>
        <p>VIEW Projects</p>
      </Link>
    </div>
```

currently the products component is displaying in a grid container.
The Link for the webdesign takes up two grid-rows. when clicking on the webdesign
link I want to be able to show only the two other links in one row not both rows as well.

[Github code](https://github.com/cloudpc7/designo)

I don't really know how to display a partial component based on someone clicking the link when navigating to another page. I would like to know if there is a function for this.